# TypeScript: Unexpected Assignment of Computed Property with Union Type in Object Literal

Tags: javascript, typescript

```js
declare const GenderChoices: {
  readonly Male: "Male";
  readonly Female: "Female";
};
type GenderChoice = (typeof GenderChoices)[keyof typeof GenderChoices];

type Person = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
};
type PersonById = Record<number, Person>;

type PersonByGender = Partial<Record<GenderChoice, PersonById>>;

const gender: GenderChoice = "Male";

const obj = {
  [gender]: false
};

const personByGender: PersonByGender = obj; // this does not work as expected

function testFunction(gender: GenderChoice) {
  const obj = {
    [gender]: false,
  };
  const personByGender: PersonByGender = obj; // this works although the type of obj on the right side does not match the type of the variable on the left side
}
```

The line `const personByGender: PersonByGender = obj;` outside the function does not work as expected but the same code inside the function runs without any error.

I had asked the same question on [twitter](https://twitter.com/kunaldeewan/status/1700928813360710129) and two well known typescript experts showered their opinions.

Comment: There is a Github issue about this https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38663

Comment: "I just wanted to have an open discussion about this here before opening a ticket on github."  Could you please [edit] to explicitly phrase this as a proper question?  Asking for "an open discussion" would be off-topic here.  I assume @Behemoth should turn their comment into an answer to whatever it turns out to be.

Comment: Note that the type of `obj` inside your function scope and outside is different, which can explain why you're getting an error. Inside the function obj type is `const obj: { [x: string]: boolean }` while out side function scope it is `const obj: { Male: boolean }`

Comment: @TBA `{ [x: string]: boolean; }` shouldn't be assignable to type `PersonByGender` either.

Comment: @jcalz you are right about the "open discussion" thing. removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue about this on the TypeScript Github ([Union in a computed property allows any assignment to property value #38663](https://Union%20in%20a%20computed%20property%20allows%20any%20assignment%20to%20property%20value%20#38663)). This answer tries to paraphrase the discussion in the issue and especially the explanation by [Wesley Wigham](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38663#issuecomment-651269192).

---

Essentially, the problem is the following. You want to add an non-literal `string` value computed property to an object without loosing type constraints. Non-literal because you're dealing with function arguments.

```
type Key = "foo" | "bar";

declare const keyValuePair: {
  key: Key;
  value: unknown;
};

const dict: Partial<Record<Key, string>> = {
  [keyValuePair.key]: keyValuePair.value
  // ? We would expect an error here because 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.
};
```

---

Let's break it down.

Outside the function `const gender: GenderChoice = "Male"` is defined as a literal string of `"Male"`. TypeScript can infer this computed property on a `const` object as `{ Male: boolean; }`:

```
const gender: GenderChoice = "Male";
// type GenderChoice = "Male" | "Female"           

const obj = {
  [gender]: false
};

const personByGender: PersonByGender = obj;
//    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -> ... not assignable (as expected)
```

However, as soon as we work with non-literals it gets more complicated because computed properties now produce [Index Signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures). In the scope of `testFunction()` `obj` is inferred as `{ [x: string]: boolean; }` and surprisingly the following does not produces a compiler error:

```
function testFunction(gender: GenderChoice) {
  // type GenderChoice = "Male" | "Female"
  // type PersonByGender = Partial<Record<GenderChoice, PersonById>>;
  const obj: PersonByGender = {
    [gender]: false
  };
}
```

Why is that? If neither the computed property nor the object it's added to have an index signature, TypeScript makes the types *evaporate*, meaning it doesn't add an index signature to the resulting type. For example:

```
declare var nonLiteral: string;

const obj = {a: "", b: ""};
const result = {[nonLiteral]: 0, ...obj};
// const result: { a: string; b: string; } <-- No index signature added
```

In your case the compiler considers the created index signature in `obj` in `testFunction()` not to be an [*Excess Property*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#excess-property-checks). This is the case because if the computed property name only actually edits the known names, then there could never be any excess properties. So the issue is that a computed property doesn't edit the types of the properties it may overwrite!

To me, this looks like a flaw in the compiler and will hopefully be considered to be improved.